# Mediator with JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, mediator

i am trying use the design pattern on my Mediator. In order to have my gui seperated instead of having all components in one class.

And example would be that you needed to be logged into the program before using other GUI components. Therefore creating a Mediator class that creates an instance of each gui element that each of the GUI classes (Login, addUser, ShowUser) could refer to when changeing window.

```
 public class Mediator {

        public Login login;
        public AddUser add;
        public ShowUsers su;
        public Stage stage = new Stage();
        public Mediator(){
            login = new Login(this);
            add = new AddUser(this);
            su = new ShowUsers(this);
        }
        public void showUser() throws Exception{
            su.start(stage);
        }
    }
public class ShowUsers extends Application{
    private Mediator m;
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    public ShowUsers(Mediator m){
        this.m =m;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

    }

}
```

I am getting an exepction saying:***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main***

How do i get around this if i want to use a mediator?

**Update**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Mediator m = new Mediator();
        m.showUser();

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to start several JavaFX Applications?

Comment: Yeah i have a main method that starts the mediator

Comment: In JavaFX applications you usually have one single Application and one or more Stages, but not several Applications. Please explain further if you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a Java FX Application with Application.launch. I don't think you can launch more than one Application per JVM, but I haven't tried (why would you want?). Of course you can have several Stages per application though.

Edit:
In fact the Javadoc says:
" It must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown. "

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)

Comment: That's a good thing, but the question is where to apply a design pattern. So what is your actual goal?

Comment: My goal is to have a somewhat controller and how i would use that to change components in my GUI?

Comment: the issue of having all my GUI in one class as an example: My login Gui should not be in the same class as my Add user GUI Because you shouldnt be able to add user unless your logged in

Comment: It's hard to tell from here, but coming from Swing, the Mediator is usually the parent Pane.

Comment: okay i might have asked this question in a wrong way i think i need rephrase

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `Platform.runLater()` (See [Platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html)).

This will place your application on the correct thread. However, you still have to think about initializing the JavaFX Toolkit by either a) extending Application with `Main` instead of `ShowUsers` or b) using a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) if you are using this from within a Swing application.